# jQuery accordion-style FAQ with + and -

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I'm trying to make a FAQ accordion with + and - signs in front of the questions [like this.](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/lib/images/bootstrap/bootstrap-accordion-menu-with-plus-minus-icon.png) It almost works except when I click the opened section again, the minus stays as a minus. Is there any way to make it a plus? I tried writing the first commented line for that, but it doesn't seem to work. Beware, I don't know what I'm doing with jQuery and am just winging it based on what I see and know in other languages.

```
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

  //Check if this panel is minus and change it to plus *** THIS DOESN'T WORK ***
  if($('img', this).attr('src') == 'minus.png'){
     $('img', this).attr('src', 'plus.png');
  }

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Change this panel to minu
  $('img', this).attr('src','minus.png');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

  //Change other panels to plus
  $(".accordion-toggle img").not($('img', this)).attr('src', 'plus.png');

});

<!-- CSS -->
<style>
  .accordion-toggle {margin-top: 10px; cursor: pointer; background-color: #F0F0F0; padding: 16px 24px 19px 0px;}
  .accordion-toggle h4 { line-height: 26px; font-weight: 600;}
  .accordion-content {display: none;  background-color: #F0F0F0; padding: 1px 425px 34px 56px; line-height: 25px; }
  .accordion-content.default {display: block;}
  #accordion {
     font-family: "Open Sans"; color: #0D253E; font-size: 16px;
  }
  .plus {
     margin: 3px 16px 3px 20px; float: left;
  }
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-toggle"><h4><img class="plus" src="plus.png" height="20px"/>Question?</h4></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Content text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-toggle"><img class="plus" src="plus.png" height="20px"/><h4>Question?</h4></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Content text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-toggle"><h4><img class="plus" src="plus.png" height="20px"/>Question?</h4></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Content text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-toggle"><h4><img class="plus" src="plus.png" height="20px"/>Question?</h4></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Content text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you've check given bootstrap's accordion example? https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: @eeya Looks cool and simple. Problem is, I really suck at jQuery and, if possible, I'd like to make this work. If I can't do it, I'll probably start learning, but I don't really have time right now. Thanks for the link, though!

Comment: Can you kindly update your question that includes your `html` and `css`?

Comment: @eeya Edited. It's just missing the `<script>` tags and `$(document).ready(function($) {`.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to change the way you've called your `img` attribute inside every of your `div.accordion-toggle` DOM element(s)

```
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {

    // Check if this panel is minus and change it to plus *** THIS DOESN'T WORK ***

    // @eeya: Change it like this: (Find every img elements
    // under the .accordion-toggle element that called
    // the event listener
    if ($(this).find('img').attr('src') === 'minus.png') {
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'plus.png');
    }

    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

    //Change this panel to minu
    $('img', this).attr('src','minus.png');

    //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    //Change other panels to plus
    $(".accordion-toggle img").not($('img', this)).attr('src', 'plus.png');

});
```

Hope this helps for your case.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't change anything. I wonder why it's not working. In theory it should, right?

Comment: Yes, Your primary objective here is to change the `plus` image to `minus` image by the time the selected `div.accordion-toggle` was selected right?